# Xamarin Forms: Best way to pass parameters to a ContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, implementation

I should have an opinion/advice from you. I'm creating an app where a user can select one option from a Grid.

I have a function that from a List of DashSquare create a Grid.

```
 public class DashSquare {
     public string IconImage { get; set; }
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public int Column { get; set; }
     public int Row { get; set; }
     public Type NavigateType { get; set; }
 }
```

After a tap on an Grid item I'm opening another ContentPage, one for each option in the grid. I have to pass to this new page always the same parameters. Now I'm using a generic function in the main ContentPage

```
 widget.Tapped += async (s, e) => {
     var page = Activator.CreateInstance(e.Page) as Page;
     await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
 };
```

to open a new page but I can't pass params. My idea is to create a interface IMyPage and each page depends from ContentPage and IMyPage.

How can I check if this page implements IMyPage? How can I pass params? Is there a right way to implement it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can pass it via constructor, Inject via dependency, or expose public properties and set those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the same code with `Activator.CreateInstance()`. You just need to use the `CreateInstance()` overload like so:

```
var page = Activator.CreateInstance(e.Page, param1, param2) as Page;
await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```